# how to display mysql database values as text in gridview using mysql if statement

Tags: mysql, gridview

I have a database which comprises of four columns but i would like to display the last column (iActive), which has values 1 and 0 only under it as( if 1 Display as Active else if 0 display as In-active) in my formload gridview. I tried with case method too but doesn't work.
 Below is my gridview stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_chargegridview`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_chargegridview`()
BEGIN
    SELECT chargeRate AS `Charge Rate`, TransDate AS `Transaction Date`, iActive AS `Active`
    FROM t_pi_msg_charge_rate;
    SELECT DataID,
    CASE iActive
    WHEN "1" THEN Active
    WHEN "0" THEN Inactive
    END AS Active
    FROM t_pi_msg_charge_rate;

END$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try

```
SELECT DataID,
CASE 
WHEN iActive == "1" THEN "Active"
WHEN iActive == "0" THEN "Inactive"
END AS "Active"
FROM t_pi_msg_charge_rate;
```

//edit if iActive is integer and not string, remove quotes from "0" and "1"